# How can I give 2 independent results in a function?

Tags: python, function, import, module

Well, I'm starting to code in python, and as a homework I'll should make a function, that later on It will be called by another different function, but i got a problem, I must give this two results independently in the main function (by that way I would give a table with a better look in my final function)  my code looks like this:

```
def converpies(cant):
    total = 0.305*cant
    total2 = cant / 0.305
    return total, total2

from lab8 import converpies

def prueba2():
    cant = 1
    pies = 1
    metros = 1
    print ('pies','\t', 'metros', '\t', 'metros', '\t', 'pies') 
    while cant != 20:
        resultado = converpies(cant)
        print (pies ,'\t', resultado,'\t', metros)
        cant = cant + 1
        pies = pies + 1
        metros = metros + 1
```

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you mean by independently returning the results? Do you want the results to be assigned to different variables?

Comment: Maybe you mean: `total, total2 = converpies(cant)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the different elements from a tuple with the (zero-based) `tupl[index]` notation.

In your case `resultado[0]` for the first, and `resultado[1]` for the second element, eg:

```
def converpies(cant):
    total = 0.305*cant
    total2 = cant / 0.305
    return (total, total2)

from lab8 import converpies

def prueba2():
    cant = 1
    pies = 1
    metros = 1
    print ('pies','\t', 'metros', '\t', 'metros', '\t', 'pies') 
    while cant != 20:
        resultado = converpies(cant)
        print (pies ,'\t', resultado[0], '\t', resultado[1], metros)
        cant = cant + 1
        pies = pies + 1
        metros = metros + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this function coverpies() which returns two values.

```
def converpies(cant):
    total = 0.305*cant
    total2 = cant / 0.305
    return total, total2
```

Python allows multiple return values and it also allows multiple assignments so I think what you want to achieve is this.

```
from lab8 import converpies

def prueba2():
    cant = 1
    pies = 1
    metros = 1
    print ('pies','\t', 'metros', '\t', 'metros', '\t', 'pies') 
    while cant != 20:
        total, total2 = converpies(cant)
        cant = cant + 1
        pies = pies + 1
        metros = metros + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return multiple values from a function, they are passed as a tuple. You can therefore either access their contents by index:

```
print (pies ,'\t', resultado[0],'\t', 
       resultado[1], '\t', metros)
```

Or unpack directly to multiple names in the calling function:

```
resultado1, resultado2 = converpies(...)
```

Note you can improve the `print` using e.g.

```
'\t'.join((pies, resultado1, resultado2, metros))
```